# Como passar dados de uma iteração pra um componente?

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um Array de dados em um arquivo List.js, e quando faço a iteração desses dados em outro arquivo, gostaria que meu componente usasse do atributo **data_final** de cada objeto da iteração.

O intuito é que meu componente **Contador** seja dinamico e exiba algo diferente pra cada objeto de acordo com seu **data_final**

Abaixo os trechos dos códigos que estou usando, sem as importações e outros elementos que não interagem com o contador , desde ja agradeço a atenção e o help! Obrigado!

```
export const Lists = [
    {
        id: '1',
        referral: '',
        title: '',
        data_final: '22-4-12',
        image_url: ''

    },
    {
        id: '2',
        referral: '',
        title: '', 
        data_final: '22-4-11',
        image_url: ''
        
    },
    {
        id:'3' ,
        referral: '',
        title: '',
        data_final: '22-4-2',
        image_url: ''
        
    },
```

```
function Grid() {
  return (
   <Container>
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <RedesSociais>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img src={Twitter} alt="twitter" width="28px" height="28px"></img></a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img src={Telegram} alt="telegram" width="28px" height="28px"></img></a>
     </RedesSociais>
      <List>
       {lists.map(sorteios => {
        return (
         <Sorteios>
          <Elemento key={sorteios.id}>
           <a href={sorteios.referral} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img src={sorteios.image_url} alt={sorteios.title}/></a>
          </Elemento>
           <Contador/> // Aqui exibe direitinho a data, porém a mesma em todos!
          </Sorteios>
          )
         })}
        </List>
     </Container> 
   )
}

export default Grid;
```

Código do Contador que acaba aparecendo em todos elementos:

```
const Contador = () => {
    
    const getCountdown = () => {

// Gostaria que ao invés de `2022-5-2`, aqui fosse usado o data_final de cada objeto iterado.
    const timeRemaining = new Date(`2022-5-2`) - new Date(); 

    let countdown = {};
    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      countdown = {
        Days: Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        Hours: Math.floor((timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
        Minutes: Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      };
    }
    return countdown;
  };
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(getCountdown());

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCountdown(getCountdown());
    }, 1000);
  });

  const data = [];
  Object.entries(countdown).forEach(([unit, value]) => {
    data.push(
      <li key={Math.random().toString(16)}>
        <strong>{value}</strong> {unit}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Visor>{data}</Visor>
    </div>
  );
  
};

export default Contador;
```

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia criar uma propriedade para seu componente **Contador**, definindo que ele receba seu *data_final*. Assim para cada iteração se sua List, o Contador receberia um *data_final* diferente e trabalharia com ele isoladamente.

Exemplo no seu componente:

```
interface IContadorProps{
 date_final: string;
}

const Contador = ({ date_final }: IContadorProps) => {
    
    const getCountdown = () => {
    const timeRemaining = new Date(date_final) - new Date();

[...]
```

Na listagem:

```
<List>
 {lists.map(sorteios => {
    return (
     [...]
        <Contador date_final={sorteios.date_final} /> // Por Propriedade
     [...]
     )
 })}
</List>
```